# How to Show the Pickerview value in Textfield and hide the pickerView using barbuttonitem?

Tags: ios, size, hide, uipickerview, show

I am Having 2 Textfields `stateText` and `providerText`.If i click the first textfield means,it shows the `pickerView`.After That i will Select the `pickerView` Value.Also i have added the toolbar `barbuttonitem` in that `pickerView`.Then I have to show the pickerView value in the Textfields and hide the pickerView after selecting the value in the PickerView.Also Pointer should moves to next TextField `connectionNoText` after getting Values in TextFields.

1.How to hide the PickerView and show the value in TextField?

2.How to show the pickerview in the Bottom of the View irrespective of phone size?

This is my Source Code:

NewConnectionviewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];

//ScrollView
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + 510.0)];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];


//statePickerView
_statePickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view. frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, 216)];
_statePickerView.delegate = self;
_statePickerView.dataSource = self;
_statePickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
[_statePickerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
[self.view addSubview:_statePickerView];

//providerPickerView
_providerPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view. frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, 216)];
_providerPickerView.delegate = self;
_providerPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
[_providerPickerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
[self.view addSubview:_providerPickerView];

//ToolBar
UIToolbar *toolBar= [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,44)];
[toolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(hidePickerView:)];
toolBar.items = @[barButtonDone];
barButtonDone.tintColor=[UIColor lightTextColor];
[barButtonDone setEnabled:YES];
[_statePickerView addSubview:toolBar];
//[_providerPickerView addSubview:toolBar];

//GettingView
[self stateView];
[self providerView];
[self connectionNoView];
[self addTestView];

}


-(void)hidePickerView:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
NSLog(@"clicked");
[self.selectState resignFirstResponder];

}


-(void)stateView
{
UIView *stateView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, 80)];
stateView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[scrollView addSubview:stateView];

//stateLabel
UILabel *stateLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(stateView.frame.origin.x+20,35, 70, 20)];
[stateLabel setText:@"State"];
[stateLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[stateView addSubview:stateLabel];

//TextField
NSLog(@"stateViewSize==>>%f",stateView.frame.origin.y);
stateText = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(stateView.frame.origin.x+110, 30, 150, 40)];
stateText.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
stateText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[stateText setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
[stateText setPlaceholder:@"select State"];
[stateText setTag:0];
[stateView addSubview:stateText];
[stateText setDelegate:self];
}


-(void)providerView
{
UIView *providerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height+80, self.view.frame.size.width, 80)];
providerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
[scrollView addSubview:providerView];
 NSLog(@"providerViewsize==>>%f",providerView.frame.origin.y);

//providerLabel

UILabel *providerLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(providerView.frame.origin.x+20, 35, 70, 20)];
[providerLabel setText:@"Provider"];
[providerLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[providerView addSubview:providerLabel];

//TextField
providerText = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(providerView.frame.origin.x+110,30, 150, 40)];
providerText.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[providerText setPlaceholder:@"select Provider"];
providerText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[providerText setTag:1];
[providerText setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
[providerView addSubview:providerText];
[providerText setDelegate:self];
}

-(void)connectionNoView
{

UIView *connectionNoView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height+160, self.view.frame.size.width, 150)];
connectionNoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[scrollView addSubview:connectionNoView];
NSLog(@"connectionNoViewsize==>>%f",connectionNoView.frame.origin.y);
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
// Show UIPickerView


if (textField.tag ==0)
{
    //stateText.inputView = _statePickerView;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        _statePickerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-216,self.view.frame.size.width, 216);
    }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     }];
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@""
                                                   message:@"Please select state first."
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
return NO;
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {

return 1;//Or return whatever as you intend
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

if([thePickerView isEqual:_statePickerView])
{
return [STATE_ARRAY count];
}
else
{
  return [PROVIDER_ARRAY count];
}
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

if([thePickerView isEqual:_statePickerView])
{
    return [STATE_ARRAY objectAtIndex:row];
}
else
{
    return [PROVIDER_ARRAY objectAtIndex:row];
}
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
NSString *firstPickerViewValue;
NSString *secondPickerViewValue;
if ([pickerView isEqual:_statePickerView])
{
    firstPickerViewValue = [STATE_ARRAY objectAtIndex:row];
    [_providerPickerView selectRow:row inComponent:0 animated:YES];
    secondPickerViewValue = [PROVIDER_ARRAY objectAtIndex:row];
    [_providerPickerView reloadAllComponents];
    [stateText setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",firstPickerViewValue]];
    [providerText setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",secondPickerViewValue]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have read through the code and to be honest Im pretty confused by your approach as I tend to avoid magic numbers when laying out the UI. Anyway I think both your questions can be solved by assigning the inputView of your slate textField and assigning the inputAccessoryView to the toolbar you created in the code. 
So for example,

```
stateText.inputView = _statePickerView
```

Well that is Swift so you would have

`[stateText setInputView:_statePickerView];`

Then you set the Accessory View so

```
[stateText setInputAccessoryView: toolBar];
```

Although toolbar is only in scope inside your viewDidLoad method so you should fix that. This should be enough to get you back on the right path. To dismiss the pickerView just resignFirstResponder of the selected textField inside your hidePickerView method.

Note that your textfields are also confined to the methods they are created in so you should fix that too.

Comment: To Hide,If i write [stateText resignFirstResponder] in the HidePickerView method also.not able to hide the pickerView.Please helpme out to hide the pickerView.

Comment: Ok, so does the pickerView only appear when you press on the stateText field? And does the toolbar appear also

Comment: ToolBar also appearing with PickerView.But hidePickerView method is not calling.Why hidePickerView method is not called? How am saying means, `nslog` value is also not showing

Comment: Ok I see now. Your hidePickerView  needs to be an IBAction so change it to -(IBAction) hidePickerView { NSLog(@"clicked"); }

Comment: That should print out clicked. You need to add your selected textfield resignFirstResponder code to remove the picker view

Answer (score 0):

Finally i Found a Solution.`PickerView` itself a `ViewController` so we can't hide the `pickerView`.Alternative solution is,

1.Create the `SubView` with Height 260 and add that View to the Self.View.
(set Y Value as `Self.View.Frame.Size.height`).

2.Add the `PickerView`(default Height - 216) and `ToolBar`(default Height - 44) to that SubView.

3.In `BarButtonItem` action Move that view to the bottom.(ex.Set Frame like this) `CGRectMake(0,Self.View.Frame.Size.Height,Self.View.Frame.Size.Width,216)`